# How do I create a hotkey that will copy highlighted text into an editor?

Tags: windows-7, windows, clipboard

How do I create a shortcut key that will copy highlighted text into a new text editor instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autohotkey.

http://www.autohotkey.com/

I haven't tested it but the script would go something like this.

```
+^c::
Send ^c
Run Notepad
WinWait Untitled - Notepad
WinActivate

Send ^v
```

Oops. I'll translate it.

`+^c::` Defines  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>   <kbd>Alt</kbd>    <kbd>C</kbd>  as the hotkey.

Then it presses   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>    <kbd>C</kbd>

Then fires up Notepad, waits for it to load, then makes it the active window.

Then it presses   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>    <kbd>V</kbd>

Comment: Crap, why didn't I think of that. <3 autohotkey. Thanks!